# catch an exception for argument of log() that may be a NaN or NULL or negative in SQl server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, exception, windows-7

In SQl server 2008 R2, I need to catch an exception for argument of log() that may be a NaN or NULL or negative.

```
BEGIN TRY

  DECLARE @ab float
  select @ab = log(c.ab) FROM t1 a inner join t2 c
    on t1.id = t2.id
                  -- @ab is selected from a table, but I do not know how to 
                  -- write the query for this case combined with capturing a possible exception.
 END TRY
 BEGIN CATCH 
  EXEC sys.sp_addmessage 60000, 16, 'log argument not positive'
  RAISERROR (60000, 16, 1)
 END CATCH
```

**To my surprise, log(null) did not throw exception !!!**

I can use "if" to throw an exception here.
But, @ab will be selected from a table so it is from a column.
How to capture the exception when the @ab is selected from a table ?

Thanks

Comment: If @ab selected from table then it will either will have value or will be null. What you are doing in `log` function. post that code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a small change from the answer in your last post:

```
DECLARE @result INT
DECLARE @insidelog INT
SELECT @insidelog = field FROM tablename WHERE condition = 'met'
IF @insidelog < 0 OR @insidelog IS NULL
    BEGIN
        EXEC sys.sp_addmessage 60000, 16, 'log() argument is not positive'
        RAISERROR (60000, 16, 1)
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @result = LOG(@insidelog)
    END
```